# Place the text of the radio button inside of it

Tags: android, radio-button, custom-controls, material-components-android, android-chips

How to place the text of a radio button inside of it?

**Motivation:**

I created the menu below "hard coding" it, handling all required situations manually, such as when one button is selected, all the other buttons must be unselected.

[image]

However, it was a lot of code, and this functionality is exactly what radio groups and radio buttons already provide, except for the matter of this question: the text of the radio button is placed outside of the button.

Making some tests I ended up with the code below:

```
<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<RadioButton
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:button="@drawable/group_button"
  android:text="@string/char_A"
  />
```

Width the property *button* I managed to change the style of the radio button, and along with the *text* property I achieve this result already:

[image]

But the final task that I thought would be the simplest, I couldn't achieve yet.

I tried to hack the source of the RadioButton on Android, to find some method I could override to replace this behavior, but I ended up in a class with 13K lines of code, and I don't think I will be able to discover how it works so soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ChipGroup` to achieve the desired effect:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:selectionRequired="true"
    app:checkedChip="@+id/default_chip"
    app:singleSelection="true">
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/default_chip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:checkedIconVisible="false"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:text="A"/>
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:checkedIconVisible="false"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:text="B"/>
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:checkedIconVisible="false"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:text="C"/>
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

See also the reference for [ChipGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup) as well as the material design pages for [Chips](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

Comment: I tried this solution but the text is behind the circle

Comment: @jairhumberto - do you mean you can't see the text because of the circle?

Comment: yes, if I set a small negative margin, its possible to see that the text is placed behind the circle.

Comment: @jairhumberto - since I added a screenshot of my result, I'm sure you understand that I was a little bit surprised to hear that it does not work. Just to be on the safe side, I used my code with yet another small sample app and I can confirm that at least for some constellations of build tools/ library versions etc. the text is covered by the drawable :(  I'll try to think of some other way to achieve the desired effect yet and get back to you.

Comment: thank you, however don't bother too much with this, since if it becomes a big problem I will keep my old solution.

Comment: @jairhumberto - since the xml approach did not work I tried a custom View and override onDraw(). It works but since it relies on implementation details of RadioButton it's just too hacky... On the other hand, your RadioGroup reminds me of a ChipGroup. So I edited my answer to show how to use a ChipGroup

Answer (score 0):

Just set the radiobutton background to these alphabets image or text and then handle those events in the radiobutton onClick().

```
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:onClick="onRadioClick"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/RobotoTextViewStyle"
                    android:background="@color/amber"/>
```

Instead of color add your alphabet drawable image.

Comment: There is no other way? Create images with alphabets is a little ugly.